# Why my new array only copy and reverse first 10 elements about old array?

Tags: c, arrays, function, reverse, definition

I want to copy and reverse a array in C pointer, but I found the result can only shown first 10 elements, why?

```
Original array: 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289 324 361
Reversed array: 81 64 49 36 25 16 9 4 1 0 29274861 12333 14041000 14036848 0 0 14036820 0 14036816 0
```

my func:

```
int * reverse_copy(int *A, int N) { 
    int *B,tmp; 
    for (B=A+N-1;A<B;A++,B--){
      tmp=*A;
      *A=*B;
      *B=tmp;
    }
}
```

main

```
int * reverse_copy(int *A, int N);  
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {   
    int N = 20;int i;int *A = NULL, *B = NULL;   
    if (argc > 1)   // first command line parameter
        N = atoi(argv[1]);  
    // allocate, fill, and print input array
    A = (int*) malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        A[i] = i*i;       
    // call task function
    B = reverse_copy(A, N);     
    // free allocated memory
    free(A);
    free(B);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: most likely explanation: you're passing the wrong value for N.  But anything could be happening in the code you don't show.  That's why you should always show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @HKTonyLee `B=A+N-1`

Comment: Save time.  A good compiler, with warnings turned on would have warned about no return in `int * reverse_copy()`.

Comment: You don't show how you print the before and after values in the array.  It would be sensible to use a function for the job: `void print_array(const char *tag, const int *A, int N);` might be an appropriate signature, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters the name pf the function `reverse_copy` only confuses readers because the function copies nothing. It reverses an array in place.

So it is better to name the function simply as `reverse`.

Secondly, the function has the return type `int *` but returns nothing. There is no sense to declare the return type of the function as `int *` instead of `void` provided that the function does not allocate dynamically a new array..

As a result this statement

```
B = reverse_copy(A, N);
```

does not make sense and invokes undefined behavior.

You allocated only one array that is pointed to by the pointer A. The pointer B does not point to a newly dynamically allocated array. So this statement

```
free(B);
```

again invokes undefined behavior.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the two functions, `reverse` and `reverse_copy`, can be implemented using pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse( int *a, size_t n )
{
    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        for ( int *b = a + n; a < --b; ++a )
        {
            int tmp = *a;
            *a = *b;
            *b = tmp;
        }
    }
}

int * reverse_copy( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    int *b = NULL;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        b = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

        for ( int *p = b + n; p-- != b; ++a )
        {
            *p = *a; 
        }
    }

    return b;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = 
    { 
        0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361 
    };

    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    printf( "Original array: " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    reverse( a, N );

    printf( "Reversed array: " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    putchar( '\n' );

    printf( "Original array: " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    int *b = reverse_copy( a, N );

    printf( "Reversed array: " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", b[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    free( b );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Original array: 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289 324 361 
Reversed array: 361 324 289 256 225 196 169 144 121 100 81 64 49 36 25 16 9 4 1 0 

Original array: 361 324 289 256 225 196 169 144 121 100 81 64 49 36 25 16 9 4 1 0 
Reversed array: 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100 121 144 169 196 225 256 289 324 361
```

An alternative and more flexible approach of implementation of the function `reverse_copy` is to provide to the function an already existent/allocated array.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * reverse_copy( const int *a, size_t n, int *b )
{
    for ( const int *p = a + n; p != a; ++b )
    {
        *b = *--p;
    }

    return b;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    printf( "Original array: " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );


    int *b = malloc( 2 * N * sizeof( int ) );

    int *p = reverse_copy( a, N, b );;

    for ( const int *q = a; q != a + N; ++q, ++p )
    {
        *p = *q;
    }

    printf( "Reversed array: " );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2 * N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", b[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    free( b );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Original array: 0 1 2 3 4 5 
Reversed array: 5 4 3 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Actually, reverse func is only part I need to finish, others are fixed. Besides, I know how to reverse but reverse+copy, I need more time to think...

Answer (score 1):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse_copy(int *A, int N) { 
    int *B,tmp; 
    for (B=A+N-1;A<B;A++,B--){
      tmp=*A;
      *A=*B;
      *B=tmp;
    }
}

int main(void) {

  int numbers[20] = {0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361};

  reverse_copy(numbers, 20);

  for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {
    printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm assuming that you don't really want a new array, and you want to reverse the numbers in the existing array because otherwise why don't you just use a for loop to copy from the old array backwards? Therefore I'm guessing that you want `reverse_copy` to return `void`, i.e. not returning anything.

Apart from the return type, your function seems to work OK (in a weird and dangerous way though, I wouldn't write a function that actually do `++` on any input pointer).

Edit: Now I see your main, if you want a new array this is how you'd write the whole thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse_copy(int *A, int * B, int N) { 
    for (int i = N-1;i>0;i--){
      B[N-i-1]=A[i];
    }
}

int main(void) {

  const int kLen = 20;
  int* A;
  int* B;
  A = (int*) malloc(kLen * sizeof(int));
  B = (int*) malloc(kLen * sizeof(int));

  for (int i = 0; i < kLen; i++){
    A[i] = i; 
  }

  reverse_copy(A, B, kLen);

  printf("A:");
  for( int i = 0; i < kLen; i++ ) {
    printf("%d ", A[i]);
  }

  printf("\nB:");
  for( int i = 0; i < kLen; i++ ) {
    printf("%d ", B[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  free(A);
  free(B);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why reverse_copy(numbers, 15) is 15

Comment: That's just an example, you can try call `reverse_copy(numbers, 20)` if you like, no greater than 20 though, because the array is only 20 `int`s long.

Comment: yeah the reverse func is truly change old array but the result is only show reverse first 10 element,why?

Comment: It is not though, you can run `reverse_copy(numbers, 20)` and get the right result.